# GCC weird error at header file when using linter-gcc at atom editor

Tags: c, gcc, editor, clang, atom-editor

I'm getting a weird error at C header files when linting with linter-gcc at atom. The error is this:

```
cc1: error: output filename specified twice
```

This error is generated by: gcc 5.2.1, ubuntu 15.10.

The same error is generated by gcc 5.3.0 at my linux arch system 4.5.0-1 ARCH.

When I checked with clang 3.7.1 all went fine.

Note that I can compile the program normally. The error is generated only inside atom editor or when I run this command at my terminal:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -fsyntax-only -c -fmax-errors=0 /path/to/headerfile.h
```

But when I run:

```
clang -Wall -fsyntax-only -c /path/to/headerfile.h
```

Nothing was printed.

EDIT: It seems that it's not linter-gcc's bug as I contacted the package's creator via his github account.

So my question is: What's is the source of this error? Is there a way to solve it? What's causing it?

Comment: Compiling headers???

Comment: @jdarthenay No, syntax checking them.

Comment: @jdarthenay You can compile headers. The output is headerfile.h.gch

Comment: What is the header content that seems to be the cause of the problem?  Is it a system header file or an homegrown header file?

Comment: Apparently [cc1 takes the preprocessor result as an input](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77781), you might try to see with `gcc -S` what is the preprocessor result.

Comment: @user3629249 It's a homegrown headerfile. The error happens at every homegrown headerfile and not at system headerfiles.

Comment: Please run gcc with --verbose option and attach output to question. I am pretty sure, that everything will become clear.

Comment: please post the content of one of those homegrown header files that is refusing to compile.  Then we can be much more helpful in debugging the source of the problem.